# Can I set a default css class for an html element

Tags: css

If I define a css class, is there anyway to set that class as a default class for an html element? To clarify, I was hoping to factor out the definition of the class so it could be used by one or more css selectors or applied discreetly in the html.

For example:

```
.myclass {float:right}
h1 {class: myclass}
```

The above does not work of course, but hopefully you know what I am asking as I have not been able to find how to do this.

Comment: You want LESS or SASS.

Comment: No, because classes pertain to HTML, not CSS.

Comment: I'm with Dave on this.  I think others here are hung up on the idea of one style.  Think big picture - a ton of styles in classes you don't control.  For example: If I have a group of Bootstrap classes that I always want to Default to for a Table (or group into one new Class), then it sure would be nice to have a native CSS way of doing this without resorting to javascript or less/sass.  As a fellow C# developer, it doesn't seem like a big ask; but rather more like a feature that should have always been there.  I know the CSS gurus out there will balk and say "_that's not how CSS works_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that if you are using a CSS processor like LESS (http://lesscss.org/#-mixins) or SASS (http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins).

Comment: Such tools do not set any default class on HTML elements. They are just tools for generating CSS code and do not affect HTML at all. You can see this e.g. by checking the className property of an HTML element node in JavaScript.

Comment: True. I was just providing an alternative way to achieve the desired result. The OP needed a way to extend CSS class definitions and straight CSS does not solve for that. This is one of the reasons why solutions like LESS and SASS exist.

Answer (score 4):

Not with standard CSS, but why not just do:

```
h1 {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I know I can do that but was hoping to factor out the definition of the class so could be used by multiple element selectors or applied discreetly.

Answer (score 2):

> If I define a css class, is there anyway to set that class as a default class for an html element?

No. You can, however, select all elements and apply a rule to them:

```
* {
    foo: bar;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your repeated comment “I was hoping to factor out the definition of the class so it could be used by one or more elements or applied discreetly”, it seems that what you are really up to is how to define a set of CSS declarations so that they apply to elements in a given class *and* and some elements independently of class. The way to do this is to use a list of selectors, e.g.

```
.myclass, h1 { float:right; /* and other declarations as needed */ }
```

This is the kind of “factoring out” that you can achieve in CSS. There is no way to “factor out” “CSS classes”, because there are no CSS classes. There are classes in HTML, and you can specify rules that apply to such classes.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion and clarification. I'm mostly a C# developer and css is not my specialty.

Answer (score 0):

Just write the following HTML

```
<h1 class="mylass"> .... </h1>
```

and write *VALID* CSS

i.e.

```
.myclass {float: right}
```

Comment: Thanks. I know I can do that but was hoping to factor out the definition of the class so could be used by multiple elements or applied discreetly.

Comment: @Dave - That is the whole point of class - You can use it for multiple elements on in a HTML document. Indeed an tag in a HTML document can have multiple classes.

Comment: Yes, I know, I just wanted to for example assign to all <h1> elements by default and ALSO be able to use on discrete elements in the markup. A factoring out of the class definition if you will so could be used for both.

Comment: @dave - There is an order. For a tag the CSS style gets superseeded by any class, and this in turn gets superseeded by the id.

Comment: Yes, I know but that is irrelevant to what I was wanting which was setting an already defined default class for an element. Am looking at SASS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but maybe you ask this because you want to have multiple html elements use the same "class"?

If that's the case you can write it like this:

```
h1, h2, span{
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Yes, pretty much. I was hoping to factor out the definition of the class so it could be used by one or more elements or applied discreetly.

Comment: You should probably also read up on CSS selectors, this site is pretty good: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/