# Is it possible to set an HTML element to have a CSS class by default

Tags: css, sass

**Given a CSS class, is it possible to set an HTML element to have that class by default?**

For example: instead of having to write `<input class="input_field">` everywhere, I would like to define `<input>` to always have `class=input_field`.

The reason for the requirement is that the class definition is supplied by a third party and is subject to change. It is included by a SASS directive. Yes, it would be possible to look up what the class definition is and duplicate it into an input element but that is what I would like to avoid having to do.

So, I am not looking for the answer to be

```
input {
   ... styles in .input_field ...
}
```

What I hope for is something like

```
input {
    class: myclass
}
```

The answer can use CSS or SASS.

**note:** I have read the closest alternative [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282373/can-i-set-a-default-css-class-for-an-html-element/) that I could find and, from that, I guess that this is not possible. But, I ask the question anyway with hope there may be another solution.

Comment: Interesting question. Although it might not be exactly what you want, you could just add the "input_field" class with JavaScript / jQuery to all inputs $('input').addClass('input_field');

Comment: Just because you've read the linked question doesn't mean that isn't still the answer to your question.

Comment: @cinnamon yes I know that! While the answers below suggested some interesting otions, the fact remains that you cannot change the behaviour of an HTML tag without applying styling either inline or by use of a CSS class or id. The answer is as per the other question - it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's wrong with just using the `input` selector, but it would be fairly trivial to add a class to a *containing* CSS element that will change the styles of the inputs.

```
<div class=input_field_container>
    <input> etc.

.input_field_container input {
    /* rules */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try with

```
input[class^="yourClass"]{
   color: blue;
}
```

Source: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

E[foo^="bar"]   an E element whose "foo" attribute value begins exactly with the string "bar"   Attribute selectors

Answer (score 0):

> input {
>       class: myclass
>   }

In SASS you can create an @extend.

```
%class-name {..}
input {
    @extend class-name
}
```

You can use %class-name to set it to only be used as an extend, or you can use .class-name and extend it or use it on its own.

Comment: Just read the post that you said didn't help you.
To clarify, this method doesn't add the class to html and doesn't output as you are describing. However you can manage your code before it is processed in this manner.